# Hide the Linux hidden files in Windows

Tags: windows, linux, file, windows-vista

Is it possible to  hide the Linux hidden files (.* files) in Windows?

Does explicitly hiding the files by changing the file properties in Windows have any effect in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to hide them automatically, but you can safely mark them all as "hidden", if your filesystem supports that.

Answer (score 8):

the command `ATTRIB +H` was very usefull for my needs; 
I wanted to hide in Windows 7 all linux *.hidden files created in my data drive (in my case D:), so I used the following command line:

`C:\>attrib +h D:\*.hidden /S`

and it worked very fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can open your command prompt, then use `attrib +H` on your hidden files. type `attrib /?` for more info